# Center vertical image on top image

Tags: html, css

from some helped from others in stackoverflow i already horizontal my text on image. Right now i want the text at center on vertical also. Thank you very guys

```
<body>
    <div class="images">
    <img src="image.jpg" id="imageid" />
    <div class="texts" id="text">
        <a href="#">Gallery 1</a>
    </div>
</div>

.images {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    float: left;
}

.texts {
    left: 0;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: add this  `top:50%;
    transform: translatey(-50%);` to `.texts` [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ty9owm5d/)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look into this explanatory site http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/

You can use `vertical-align:middle` property to align the image to the text.

Here is a sample http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_vertical-align